# Can I take an HDMI input to my laptop?

Tags: video, hdmi

I have a device whose video-out is HDMI. My laptop has an HDMI port. My laptop is running Linux.

Can I view the device's video-out on my laptop? How?

Comment: What is your laptop model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I view the device's video-out on my laptop? How?

Yes you can. However you will need to buy a device known as a [frame grabber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_grabber). One of its **input** connectors needs to be HDMI (The HDMI connector on your laptop is only used for **output**).

[image]

To repeat: Yes you can **with extra hardware**.

Comment: I've been using that for both work and homelab purposes - the capture cards have gotten *really* cheap on the low end, and emulate a webcam on the capture computer end.

Comment: It is funny how manyh old ansers I run into this month. Many with outdated information. (valid 5 years ago, but no longer correct).

Comment: Well I was/am debating putting up an updated answer :D

Answer (score 3):

No. HDMI ports on a laptop are designed to only be used as output.