# Can I connect my desktop tower to my laptop's screen?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer

I have a laptop and a desktop tower unit. I don't have monitor for the desktop. But I want to access the desktop OS and work on it. I tried to find a solution but couldn't find one.

Can I use my laptop's screen as a monitor for this desktop? Is it even possible?

Comment: @gronostaj the accepted answer talks about having 2 monitors. I have only one, i.e., my laptop screen.

Comment: Already has answers? No it doesn't.

Comment: We have many questions asking about this already. Try looking at the other answers, not just the accepted ones and actually look into the tools and solutions they suggest. Tell us what you have tried and why those solutions don't work. https://superuser.com/search?q=laptop+as+monitor

Comment: @Mokubai all those tools have to install something on desktop. How is even that possible without seeing what's in desktop? For example SpaceDesk. Absolutely ridiculous to close this question without even understanding problem.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/616163/can-i-take-an-hdmi-input-to-my-laptop

Comment: One way or another you will need to buy hardware. Either a video capture device or a monitor.

Comment: Long story short, you will have to buy a monitor. Without a monitor, the computer will not know what resolution to use and you get a tiny desktop, even if you use remote software to take over the computer. RDP into the computer is an option that uses the local resolution, but RDP needs to be enabled first.Configuring RDP using Powershell remote execution may work, but is very complicated.